# How to set permission for discussion tag in liferay 6.1?

Tags: liferay-6

I used `<liferay-ui:discussion>` to allow user comment on journal article. Now users are able to add, edit, delete comments.

However, the problem is any users logged in are able to edit as well as delete all comments posted by other users.

I am trying to find a way to limit the permission so that the owner can only edit his/her own posted comments.

How can I do that?

Comment: which version of liferay you are using?

Comment: I mentioned in the question title. I'm using 6.1

Answer (score 0):

You should use the "control panel" to edit this kind of permission based on roles.

You can find the Liferay official documentation here : http://www.liferay.com/fr/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/lp-6-1-ugen15-roles-and-permissions-0